# Is an hourly scheduler job on Heroku essentially free?

Tags: heroku, scheduler

Heroku Docs state:

> Previously, Heroku included “1 free dyno” with each app, which is
>   equivalent to between 672 and 744 dyno-hours (depending on the length
>   of the month). With this switch to dyno-hours, we are converting the
>   included free dyno to a fixed 750 free dyno-hours.

Does that mean "fixed" per month?

A task per hour would use up those hours within a month which would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single application on Heroku is entitled to 750 hours free each month.  These hours can be used however you like.

Comment: What constitutes a "dyno-hour" ? is itmeasuring the total time any client has an interactive session active with any page on the web site ?

Comment: Wall clock time that the dyno is running

Comment: If you don't mind explaining the Dyno to me a little bit more I'd appreciate it. I did read the faq's at Heroku but I don't quite get it. If no one at all is interacting with my web site, the dyno will time out and stop running. As soon as anyone hits the web site, it will start up again. Every time someone hits the site the time out clock resets. Many people (under 100) can hit the web site (simply viewing it) and the one dyno can handle it. Is this correct ? Thank you.

Comment: This is more a question for the Heroku mailing list, or another SO question

Comment: I understand and will do just that. If I learn some helpful answers I will post a link here.